# how to read nested array in JSON from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

i have a json array like below.

```
[
[
"{"category_id":1,"category_name":"cake","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":2,"category_name":"briyani","image_id":6}",
"{"category_id":3,"category_name":"Indian Breads","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Tandoori","image_id":5}",
"{"category_id":5,"category_name":"Seafood Delight","image_id":10}",
"{"category_id":6,"category_name":"Vegetarian","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":7,"category_name":"Curry","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":8,"category_name":"Biryani","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":9,"category_name":"Dessert","image_id":13}",
"{"category_id":10,"category_name":"Chefs Recommendation","image_id":0}",
"{"category_id":11,"category_name":"Beverages","image_id":11}",
"{"category_id":12,"category_name":"Alcohol","image_id":4}",
"{"category_id":13,"category_name":"Buffet","image_id":0}"
],
[
"{"subcategory_id":1,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Beer","image_id":0}",
"{"subcategory_id":2,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Wine","image_id":0}"
],
[
"{"sub_id":1,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Beer","image_id":0}",
"{"sub_id":2,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Wine","image_id":0}"
],
```

how to read only category_name from java script? i want to read all the category name from java script.

Comment: You have an array of arrays of strings, containing JSON. You have to parse those strings first to JavaScript objects. I.e. you probably end up to parse the data twice. Then see [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). Better yet: Fix the code that generates the JSON so that you don't produce nested JSON.

Comment: Your data looks like it is malformed. What's with the `"`s before every `{` and after every `}`?

Comment: This isn't even valid JSON (illegal quoting) or even a valid javascript string.  You will first have to make it valid and then use `JSON.parse()` to make it into a Javascript data structure and then and only then can you run some code on it to fetch the `category_name` poperties.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
items: [
array1:[
{"category_id":1,"category_name":"cake","image_id":0},
{"category_id":2,"category_name":"briyani","image_id":6},
{"category_id":3,"category_name":"Indian Breads","image_id":0},
{"category_id":4,"category_name":"Tandoori","image_id":5},
{"category_id":5,"category_name":"Seafood Delight","image_id":10},
{"category_id":6,"category_name":"Vegetarian","image_id":0},
{"category_id":7,"category_name":"Curry","image_id":0},
{"category_id":8,"category_name":"Biryani","image_id":0},
{"category_id":9,"category_name":"Dessert","image_id":13},
{"category_id":10,"category_name":"Chefs Recommendation","image_id":0},
{"category_id":11,"category_name":"Beverages","image_id":11},
{"category_id":12,"category_name":"Alcohol","image_id":4},
{"category_id":13,"category_name":"Buffet","image_id":0}
],
array2:[
{"subcategory_id":1,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Beer","image_id":0},
{"subcategory_id":2,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Wine","image_id":0}
],
array3:[
{"sub_id":1,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Beer","image_id":0},
{"sub_id":2,"category_id":12,"subcategory_name":"Wine","image_id":0}
],]
};
```

You can read with this code snippet:

```
for(var i = 0, l = data.items.array1.length; i < l; i++) {
    var local_category_name = data.items.array1[i].category_name;
}
```